# bluetooth communication between android and .net apps

Tags: android, .net, bluetooth

Anyone please can give sample working code of connectivity and communication between android app and .net web app via **BLUETOOTH**. I've searched and find lots code examples. I've also seen **android bluetooth chat** example but none of them could solve my problem. I'm facing problem on connectivity with android and .net web app. Kindly help me regarding this to solve my problem. it should be better if anyone have working code or working example explained.

***LoginActivity.java***

```
package com.example.vivaexam;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.R.string;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;

import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChat";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Message types sent from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;

// Key names received from the BluetoothChatService Handler
public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
public static final String TOAST = "toast";

// Intent request codes
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

// Layout Views
private TextView mTitle;
private ListView mConversationView;
private EditText mOutEditText;
private Button mSendButton;

// Name of the connected device
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
// Array adapter for the conversation thread
private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
// String buffer for outgoing messages
private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
// Local Bluetooth adapter
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
// Member object for the chat services
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;

//final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

EditText usertext;
EditText pwdtext;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // Set up the window layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    setTitle("Login to your account");

    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    //myBTadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    //addListenerOnButton();
    usertext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    pwdtext= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd_edttxt);

}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ ON START ++");

    // If BT is not on, request that it be enabled.
    // setupChat() will then be called during onActivityResult
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else {
        if (mChatService == null) setupViva();
    }
}


@Override
public synchronized void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+ ON RESUME +");

    // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
    // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
    // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
   /* if (mChatService != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mChatService.getState() == BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE) {
          // Start the Bluetooth chat services
          mChatService.start();
        }
    }*/
}

private void setupViva() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");

    // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
    //mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
    //mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
    //mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

    // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
    });

    // Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(this, mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "- ON PAUSE -");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "-- ON STOP --");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
    if (mChatService != null) mChatService.stop();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "--- ON DESTROY ---");
}

private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "ensure discoverable");
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() !=
        BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}


// The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
private TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener =
    new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        if(D) Log.i(TAG, "END onEditorAction");
        return true;
    }
};

// The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothChatService
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                mTitle.append(mConnectedDeviceName);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                //mTitle.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                //mTitle.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the buffer
            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult " + resultCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
        // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the device MAC address
            String address = data.getExtras()
                                 .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

            // Get the BLuetoothDevice object
            BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            if(D) Log.d(TAG, "==== " + device);
            // Attempt to connect to the device
            mChatService.connect(device);
        }
        break;
    case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
        // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
            setupViva();
        } else {
            // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
            Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Sends a message.
 * @param message  A string of text to send.
 */
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.secure_connect_scan:
        // Launch the DeviceListActivity to see devices and do scan
        Intent serverIntent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
        return true;
    case R.id.discoverable:
        // Ensure this device is discoverable by others
        ensureDiscoverable();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

**service.java**
    package com.example.vivaexam;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;


public class BluetoothChatService {
// Debugging
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";
private static final boolean D = true;

// Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
private static final String NAME = "BluetoothChat";

// Unique UUID for this application
//private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

// Member fields
private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
private final Handler mHandler;
private AcceptThread mAcceptThread;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
private int mState;

// Constants that indicate the current connection state
public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

/**
 * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
 * @param context  The UI Activity Context
 * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
 */
public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
    mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mState = STATE_NONE;
    mHandler = handler;
}

/**
 * Set the current state of the chat connection
 * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
 */
private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
    mState = state;

    // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
    mHandler.obtainMessage(LoginActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

/**
 * Return the current connection state. */
public synchronized int getState() {
    return mState;
}

/**
 * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
 * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume() */
public synchronized void start() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
    if (mAcceptThread == null) {
        mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        mAcceptThread.start();
    }
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
 */
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

    // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
    if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    mConnectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

/**
 * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
 * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
 * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
 */
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected");

    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}

    // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
    mConnectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(LoginActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(LoginActivity.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

/**
 * Stop all threads
 */
public synchronized void stop() {
    if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");
    if (mConnectThread != null) {mConnectThread.cancel(); mConnectThread = null;}
    if (mConnectedThread != null) {mConnectedThread.cancel(); mConnectedThread = null;}
    if (mAcceptThread != null) {mAcceptThread.cancel(); mAcceptThread = null;}
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionFailed() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(LoginActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(LoginActivity.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
 */
private void connectionLost() {
    setState(STATE_LISTEN);

    // Send a failure message back to the Activity
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(LoginActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(LoginActivity.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

/**
 * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
 * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
 * (or until cancelled).
 */
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;

        // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
        while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                    switch (mState) {
                    case STATE_LISTEN:
                    case STATE_CONNECTING:
                        // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                        connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                        break;
                    case STATE_NONE:
                    case STATE_CONNECTED:
                        // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (D) Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread");
    }

    public void cancel() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "cancel " + this);
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
        }
    }
}


/**
 * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
 * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
 * succeeds or fails.
 */
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
        // given BluetoothDevice
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(LoginActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(buffer);

            // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            mHandler.obtainMessage(LoginActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                    .sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

`

Comment: adding a working example of what you have found on the internet and why it doesn't work for you might make your question more specific.

Comment: please show what you have tried, and an explanation of why/how it didn't work.

Comment: define how you understand the notion of communication between a web app and a bluetooth client. are you talking about http over bluetooth, or is the web app also a bluetooth server ?

Comment: i'm talking about bluetooth web app.

Comment: i've updated my question. please see now.

Comment: no one have any answer or working example please???